# How to make comparisons between two large lists fast python

Tags: python

I would like to know if there's any way to make this code run more fast. It's taking me 47 seconds and it has to compare everything not just the elements in the same position.

```
pixels = list(mensagem)
arrayBits = []
for i in pixels:
    for j in tabela:
        if i == j[0]:
            arrayBits.append(j[1])
```

Here's the hole code but I think the only reason why it's taking so long is the one I asked. Sorry about my english, I'm portuguese.

```
def codifica(mensagem, tabela, filename):
tamanho = np.shape(mensagem)
largura = tamanho[0]
if len(tamanho)==2:
    altura = tamanho[1]
else:
    altura = 0

pixels = list(mensagem)
arrayBits = []
for i in pixels:
    for j in tabela:
        if i == j[0]:
            arrayBits.append(j[1])

arraySemVirgulas = np.array(arrayBits).ravel() # tirar as virgulas
arrayJunto = ''.join(arraySemVirgulas) # juntar todos os bits
array = list(map(int,arrayJunto)) # coloca-los numa lista
count = 0
while(len(array)%8!=0):
    array.append(0)
    count += 1

array = np.array(array)
arrayNovo = array.reshape(-1,8)

decimais = convBi(arrayNovo)
array_char = ['' for i in range(len(decimais)+5)]
j = 2
for i in decimais:
    a = chr(i)
    array_char[j] = a
    j += 1

array_char[0] = str(count) 
array_char[1] = str(len(str(largura))) 
array_char[2] = str(len(str(altura)))
array_char[3] = str(largura) 
array_char[4] = str(altura)

ficheiro = open(filename,"wb")
for i in array_char:
    ficheiro.write(i)
ficheiro.close()
```

Comment: If you're more comfortable with Portuguese, you can always try [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com)...

Comment: What is inside the lists? if you are dealing with numbers only, then using numpy arrays and its search functions np.where, for example.  Python loops are very slow, and if you can transfer some of them for the inside of numpy functions you should get a very good speedup

Comment: pixels is something like this: [162, 162, 162, 161, 162, 157, 163, 161, 166, 162, 162, 160, 155, 163, 160, 155, 157, 156, 161, 161, 154, 156, 154, 157, 153, 157, 154, 152, 156]
and tabela is something like: [[43, '1101011'], [44, '1100010'], [45, '1010100'], [46, '0111101'], [47, '0110110'], [48, '0111111'], [49, '0110101'], [50, '0111010'], [51, '0111100'], [52, '1000010'], [53, '1010011'], [54, '1100011'], [55, '1101001'], [56, '1110110'], [57, '1111100'], [95, '1110101']]

Comment: what do you mean by 'compare'? what is 'equal' in this case?

Comment: You definitely need to use numpy, Alexandra.  It will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: i == j[0] is the equal in this case. I need to compare the values of the pixels with the first elements of the tabela, and if they match, the second element of the tabela (btw it means table in english) is added to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be faster if you replace the iteration

```
for i in pixels:
    for j in tabela:
        if i == j[0]:
            arrayBits.append(j[1])
```

with a dictionary lookup

```
tabela_dict = dict(tabela)
for i in pixels:
    if i in tabela_dict :
        arrayBits.append(tabela_dict[i])
```

Comment: I like it. It does assume that the first elements of all pairs in tabela_dict are unique though.

Comment: @Nicolas78 if they are not unique, the dictionary construction would be more involved, but the end result almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using `set()` and `dict()` based containers can make it linear in time instead of O(n^2). This should speed it up:

*EDIT* simpler and probably faster version:

```
import itertools

# set of 'keys' that exist in both
keys = set(pixels) & set(el[0] for el in tabela)
# and generator comprehension with fast lookup 
elements = (element[1] for element in tabela 
        if element[0] in keys)
# this will flatten inner lists and create a list with result:
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(elements))
```

Only two runs through `tabela`, both with time complexity O(n).

If `pixels` are not unique, and corresponding values from `tabela` should be multiplicated for every occurence of pixel, this should be used:

```
import itertools

# set of 'keys' that exist in both
keys = set(pixels) & set(el[0] for el in tabela)
# and generator comprehension with fast lookup 
elements = lambda key: tabela[key][1] if key in keys else []
# this will flatten inner lists and create a list with result:
flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable
result = list(flatten(elements(pixel) for pixel in pixels))
```

Comment: This makes my code run in 1 second but the file is different from the other with my slow code. The length is the same though. I'm going to do some code ''decompress'' the file to see if it's like the original.

Comment: @Alexandra this code is broken, once you have pixels with the same value, the length of output will become shorter than it should be.

Comment: I thought that pixels are unique. Anyway, algorithm is the same - first you generate set of values of interest, then you iterate checking in this set. It is still average linear complexity this way. I prepare a fix in a moment

Comment: here you go. @lenik, does it satisfy you now? ;) BTW, now lenght of output can be longer than `len(pixels)`, because it `tabela` can be multiple entries for the same value...

Comment: it took you about 13 hours to make it look like it might work, now imagine how long will it take for OP to figure out heads and tails of your iterators and lambda functions =)